# System.OutOfMemoryException when using Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, exception, windows-7

I am getting very annoying message called "system.outofmemory.exception" while I do have a lot of unused memory in my laptop. Unless I closed and re-opened the solution, it won't letting me to continue my work.

Is there any configuration or service pack that can fix the issue ?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "Plenty of unused memory", what are the specific numbers? How much is installed and how much is free (in task manager)? I suspect it's a bug and not related to actual memory usage, but just to be sure.

Comment: @rwmnau. It is more than half of my entire laptop RAM which is 4GB. It can be a bug when they package it or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reinstalling VS and run a memory check. If there's any update that is able to correct an issue like this, it's maked as important on Microsoft Update, so be sure to run it and select all the updates marked as important. Also, check if running VS as administrator solves the problem, sometimes a normal user has some limitations (on business' networks it's possible that the IT limits memory usage by program, and windows 7 has some new security policies that I'm not sure how they work yet but running a program like adminitrator usually solves the problem).

Comment: The things happens in the middle of a work. While it is working properly, it will throw the exception. I also tried reinstalling it. I do have Administrative privilege.

Answer (score 3):

My Solution was was fine in the Visual Studio environment.

But when I was trying to execute tha builded project I was getting System.OutOfMemoryException

After few hours I change the my Comodo Antivirus Settings. I made the builded solution as trusted file.

**After that I did not have this problem any more.**

Maybe it help you... too

Comment: same here, kaspersky was my problem

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue on a daily basis on a WinXP with 4GB of RAM (only 3 utilized, obv). As soon as VS 2010 Ultimate closes onto 700 MB of memory usage, I start getting OutOfMemoryExceptions. Only redemption is to restart VS, even if I close other memory-consuming applications. I also notice that the problem sufaces faster if I run unit tests. Probably because this is a memory-intensive task.

I see two separate issues here.

1. Visual Studio reporting out of memory when there really is available memory in the OS.
2. Visual Studio goes into a malfunctional state after the exception, unable to acquire new memory freed by the OS.

1) may be OS-related and not VS, I don't know enough about memory handling in Windows XP to be sure about this. I belive 2) is a VS-problem and should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

VS reinstallation is temporary solution. Jus increase your machine Virtual memory size. this resolves this issue.

ref below link - 
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/change-virtual-memory-size#1TC=windows-7