# SSRS Report out of memory exception when run on visual studio 2012

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS 2008 R2. I have created a SSRS project in VS2012. When I try to run the report(1000+ pages) I am getting out of memory exception. When I check memory useage on windows task bar, its just half of allocated memory. Any one can help?

Comment: The report works when published under **Report Server**. I get this error only when I run this in VS 2012.

Comment: I hope they don't print out this report.

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of reasons this could be happening - for a decent troubleshooting guide, try [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2020006) and a couple of related solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910874/system-outofmemoryexception-when-using-visual-studio-2010). Best luck!